# Unable to access review queues

Tags: support, review, fun, unicoins

I purchased "Reputation to the Max" and increased my reputation by 10x.

[image: mad repz]

And like a good SE citizen, I immediately went to the review queues to do my part (for the day).

However, the review queues indicate that I don't have enough precious repz in order to perform any of the much needed reviews.

[image: Review Queue laughing at me]

I believe this must be some sort of bug within purchasing the "Reputation to the Max" power and ought to be resolved.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - clearly my question is different because I provided evidence demonstrating that I a) should have access to the queues and b) that the queues still mock my meager reputation.  I'd accept closing the other question as a duplicate of mine.  :-D

Comment: Because unicorns. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Me and my friends purchased "Cut everyone's rep". We cancelled you out. :)

Comment: I’m sorry to say this, but I bought that one too. Sorry, OP…

Comment: -1 for cutting my rep and keeping me from being able to contribute back to the community.  In the future, I would encourage you to think through the ramifications of your actions.  As the [highest close queue reviewer on Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats), I thought SO could have used some of my help.

Comment: You missed the point. The whole unicoin thing was an April Fools joke. XD

Answer (score 2):

You should divide the problem into smaller parts and solve each one individually. If you then combine the all the small solutions, you have solved the whole problem.

Comment: You are really asking the wrong question.

What you should be asking is, “Why does it matter?”

Once you have the answer to this bigger question, enlightenment will follow immediately.